# Biblatex is repeating @incollection editor

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I have a reference from a book, for which the bibtex input is

```
@incollection{weisberg_2006,
  author      = {{Weisberg}, M and {McCoy}, T and {Krot}, A},
  title       = {Systematics and Evaluation of Meteorite Classification},
  booktitle   = {{Meteorites and the early solar system II}},
  publisher   = {University of Arizona Press},
  address     = {Arizona, USA},
  year        = {2006},
  pages       = {19-52},
  chapter     = {2},
  editor      = {Lauretta, D. and McSween, H.},
}
```

And a MWE like so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document} 

in book \parencite{weisberg_2006}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

However when I call this reference with biblatex it is repeating the editors in the bibliography like shown below. Does anyone have any idea how it would be possible to change this so the editors are only mentioned once. Thanks!

> Weisberg,  M.,  McCoy,  T.,  &  Krot,  A.  (2006).  Systematics  and  evaluation  of meteorite classification (D. Lauretta & H. McSween, Eds.). In D. Lauretta & H. McSween (Eds.), Meteorites and the early solar system II. Arizona, USA, University of Arizona Press.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Not related to the issue, but `author = {{Weisberg}, M and {McCoy}, T and {Krot}, A},` should be **`author  = {Weisberg, M. and McCoy, T. and Krot, A.},`**. Family names usually don't need brace protection and given name initials should be ended with a dot.

Comment: What version of `biblatex-apa` are you using? With v9.8 (2020/04/06) I get "Weisberg, M., McCoy, T. & Krot, A. (2006). Systematics and evaluation of meteorite classification. In D. Lauretta & H. McSween (Eds.), Meteorites and the early solar system II (pp. 19–52). Arizona, USA, University of Arizona Press.", which looks much better.

Comment: See https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/86, the problem is fixed in v9.3 (2019/12/21). Update `biblatex-apa`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in versions 9.0 to 9.2 of `biblatex-apa`. It was reported in https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/86 and fixed shortly afterwards in `biblatex-apa` v9.3 (2019/12/21).

With v9.8 of `biblatex-apa` I get

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{weisberg,
  author      = {Weisberg, M. and McCoy, T. and Krot, A.},
  title       = {Systematics and Evaluation of Meteorite Classification},
  booktitle   = {Meteorites and the Early Solar System {II}},
  publisher   = {University of Arizona Press},
  address     = {Arizona, USA},
  year        = {2006},
  pages       = {19-52},
  chapter     = {2},
  editor      = {Lauretta, D. and McSween, H.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{weisberg}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Weisberg, M., McCoy, T. & Krot, A. (2006). Systematics and evaluation of meteorite classification. In D. Lauretta & H. McSween (Eds.), *Meteorites and the early solar system II* (pp. 19–52). Arizona, USA, University of Arizona Press.]

APA aficionados may have noticed that the `location` should not be printed. This will be fixed in v9.9 of `biblatex-apa`: https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues/95.

Packages like `biblatex-apa` rely on users reporting deviations from the desired style.